# Extract data from a file and place in different files based on one column value

Tags: csv, split

We will generate a csv file with below values

```
yp1234,577,1,3
yp5678,577,3,5
yp9012,132,8,9
```

I need to extract data and create files based on second column. If it's 577 then the whole line has to be extracted and placed in a separate file.
I mean I need a file having lines with second column as 577 alone and another file with second column as 132 alone

I tried using IF but didn't work

Comment: Actually posting the code that doesn't work is always a good idea.

Answer (score 37):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{ print > $2 ".csv" }' file.csv
```

This will create the two files `577.csv` and `132.csv` in your current directory.

The command above assumes that you can only have `132` or `577` as the second field. It will create one file name for each of the values found in the second field of the entire `file.csv`.

If there are other values apart from the two you are interested in, and you want to ignore those lines, do this instead:

```
awk -F, '$2 == "577" || $2 == "132" { print > $2 ".csv" }' file.csv
```

Comment: There are buggy `awk` implementations that can't use `print > $2 ".cvs"`.  On those, you would have to first compute the filename, then do the `print`: `fname = $2 ".cvs"; print > fname`.

Comment: @Kusalananda those awk implementations that fail given `print > $2 ".cvs"` aren't buggy. The meaning of `print > $2 ".cvs"` (or any other unparenthesized expression on the right side of output or input redirection) is undefined by POSIX so failing with an error is just as valid as trying to figure out what the user intended when  they wrote that code. The POSIX-defined, portable way to write that code is `print > ($2 ".cvs")`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, that would work too.

Comment: @Kusalananda Storing the file name in a variable as you suggested is fine too (and more useful if/when you also need to close() the output files), my only real point is that it's not a bug to fail given `print > $2 ".cvs"`.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, I see what I wrote back in 2019 now. Good, thanks for the comment!

Comment: FWIW I'd do this with `awk -F, '$2 ~ /^(577|132)$/ { print > ($2 ".csv") }' file.csv`.

Answer (score 3):

To extract all 577 to stdout

```
grep -e '^.*,577,.*,.*$' youfile.csv >result_extract_557.csv
```

-- edit 1
Corrected, based on @terdon's comment below to avoid false matches when at least 3 commas on line with 577.

```
grep -e '^[:alnum:]*,577,[:digit:]*,[:digit:]*$' youfile.csv >result_extract_557.csv
```

But I think his/her `awk` solution is more comprehensive.

Comment: That will match even if 577 is on another field, not the second or if it is a part of a field. For example `foo577bar` or `yp9012,132,8,577`.

Comment: I thought my commas would make it field position dependent ?

Comment: Sorry, I gave bad examples but the `.*` can also match commas so you don't know which field you're matching. Could be the second, could also be the 45th. My second complaint was wrong, you're right that the commas protect from matching `foo577bar`.

Comment: what to do if | character is used instead of ,  .

Comment: receiving below error 



grep: illegal option -- e
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: @user3116123 grep needs to handle regular expressions, do you have egrep ?

Answer (score 3):

I like terdon's `awk` solution, but for the sake of completeness, here is a suggestion using only `bash`

```
while IFS=, read -r a1 a2 a3 a4; do 
    echo "$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4" >> "$a2".csv
done < file.csv
```

It will produce files `577.csv` and `132.csv` in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/):

```
$ csvgrep -c 2 -m 577 data.csv >output.csv
```

The `-c 2` makes `cvsgrep` consider the second column, and with `-m 577` we ask it to match the string `577` in that column.

The following will be written to `output.csv`:

```
yp1234,577,1,3
yp5678,577,3,5
```

To match a number of strings and write the output to a file for each string:

```
for pattern in 577 132; do
  csvgrep -c 2 -m "$pattern" data.csv >"output-$pattern.csv"
done
```

This will create the two files `output-132.csv` and `output-577.csv`.